# How to find char in string and get all the indexes?

Tags: python, string

I got some simple code:

```
def find(str, ch):
    for ltr in str:
        if ltr == ch:
            return str.index(ltr)
find("ooottat", "o")
```

The function only return the first index. If I change return to print, it will print 0 0 0. Why is this and is there any way to get `0 1 2`?

Comment: Just so it is said, don't use str as a variable name, since it is an existing keyword in Python.

Comment: @sr2222: `str` is not a keyword, it's just a builtin name (keywords are impossible to use as variable names)

Comment: @Wooble Fair enough.  Doesn't change the fact that using it as a variable name is bad practice.  :)

Answer (score 141):

This is because `str.index(ch)` will return the index where `ch` occurs the first time. Try:

```
def find(s, ch):
    return [i for i, ltr in enumerate(s) if ltr == ch]
```

This will return a list of all indexes you need.

P.S. Hugh's answer shows a generator function (it makes a difference if the list of indexes can get large). This function can also be adjusted by changing `[]` to `()`.

Comment: Using `enumerate`, nice solution!

Comment: ch must be a single character? I tried it using `ch = '&#'` and `s = &#1053;&#1072;&#1088;&#1086;&#1076;` and that didn't work.

Comment: @ChrisNielsen indeed, this won't work for longer substrings because `enumerate` iterates over characters in `s` and thus `ltr == ch` can only ever be `True` if `ch` is a single character.

Answer (score 26):

I would go with Lev, but it's worth pointing out that if you end up with more complex searches that using re.finditer may be worth bearing in mind (but re's often cause more trouble than worth - but sometimes handy to know)

```
test = "ooottat"
[ (i.start(), i.end()) for i in re.finditer('o', test)]
# [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]

[ (i.start(), i.end()) for i in re.finditer('o+', test)]
# [(0, 3)]
```

Answer (score 19):

[Lev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11122355/5987) is the one I'd use, however here's something based on your original code:

```
def find(str, ch):
    for i, ltr in enumerate(str):
        if ltr == ch:
            yield i

>>> list(find("ooottat", "o"))
[0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 16):

```
def find_offsets(haystack, needle):
    """
    Find the start of all (possibly-overlapping) instances of needle in haystack
    """
    offs = -1
    while True:
        offs = haystack.find(needle, offs+1)
        if offs == -1:
            break
        else:
            yield offs

for offs in find_offsets("ooottat", "o"):
    print offs
```

results in

```
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def find_idx(str, ch):
    yield [i for i, c in enumerate(str) if c == ch]

for idx in find_idx('babak karchini is a beginner in python ', 'i'):
    print(idx)
```

output:

```
[11, 13, 15, 23, 29]
```

Answer (score 4):

Get all the position in just one line

```py
word = 'Hello'
to_find = 'l'

# in one line
print([i for i, x in enumerate(word) if x == to_find])
```

Answer (score 1):

As the rule of thumb, NumPy arrays often outperform other solutions while working with POD, Plain Old Data. A string is an example of POD and a character too. To find all the indices of only one char in a string, NumPy ndarrays may be the fastest way:

```
def find1(str, ch):
  # 0.100 seconds for 1MB str 
  npbuf = np.frombuffer(str, dtype=np.uint8) # Reinterpret str as a char buffer
  return np.where(npbuf == ord(ch))          # Find indices with numpy

def find2(str, ch):
  # 0.920 seconds for 1MB str 
  return [i for i, c in enumerate(str) if c == ch] # Find indices with python
```

Comment: This might be true for a 1MB input string, but with a short string the second method is much faster: I tested 1 million iterations on a 7-character string, and find1() required 6199ms, find2() only 825ms.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simplest way:

```
def find(ch, string1):
    return [i for i in range(len(string1)) if string1[i]==ch]
```

No external libraries just simple python =)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "abcdabcdabcd"
print(x)
l = -1
while True:
    l = x.find("a", l+1)
    if l == -1:
        break
    print(l)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Arvind : Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind to extend your answer for fellow programmers to understand; how exactly it helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly modified version of [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11122432/311567)'s answer that works if `ch` could be more than one character in length.

```py
def find(term, ch):
    """Find all places with ch in str
    """
    for i in range(len(term)):
        if term[i:i + len(ch)] == ch:
            yield i
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers have two main flaws:

1. They do a Python loop through the string, which is horrifically slow, or
2. They use numpy which is a pretty big additional dependency.

```
def findall(haystack, needle):
    idx = -1
    while True:
        idx = haystack.find(needle, idx+1)
        if idx == -1:
            break
        yield idx
```

This iterates through `haystack` looking for `needle`, always starting at where the previous iteration ended. It uses the builtin `str.find` which is much faster than iterating through `haystack` character-by-character. It doesn't require any new imports.

Comment: This seems to be the same as [the 2012 answer from Hugh Bothwell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11122388/674039)

Comment: @wim Wow you’re right. Not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

To embellish the five-star one-liner posted by @Lev and @Darkstar:

`word = 'Hello'`
`to_find = 'l'`
`print(", ".join([str(i) for i, x in enumerate(word) if x == to_find]))`

This just makes the separation of index numbers more obvious.
Result will be:   `2, 3`

Answer (score -1):

You could try this

```
def find(ch,string1):
    for i in range(len(string1)):
        if ch == string1[i]:
            pos.append(i)
```