# Finding the Index of a character within a string

Tags: string, python-2.7, indexing

This may be worded incorrectly because I'm a wee beginner, but if I have a string how to I find a certain characters index like you can with the .index thing in lists.

With a list it makes sense:

```
 l = ["cat", "dog", "mouse"]

 animal = l.index["dog"]
```

will return [1], but how do I do the same thing with strings . . .

```
 s = "mouse"

 animal_letter = s.index["s"]
```

it says there is no attribute .index

Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: `animal_letter = s.index("s")` don't used brackets.  `l.index["dog"]` does not work either.

Comment: Can't find a definitive answer to this, is there a difference between my method and yours? s.find vs s.index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [string.find](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) method.

```
s = "mouse"
animal_letter = s.find('s')
print animal_letter
```

It returns the 0-based index (0 is the first character of the string) or -1 if the pattern is not found.

```
>>> "hello".find('h')
0
>>> "hello".find('o')
4
>>> "hello".find("darkside")
-1
```

Comment: Does this work in scenarios like "hello".find('l') . I think it will return first l letter in the string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11122355/7704650 hope this will work in those kind of scenarios.