# how to extract a output after symbol in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would extract all the numbers after a symbol contained in a output. Which is the better suited for the purpose, regular expressions ?

for eg i have an output as `172.4.5.3/32` and i need to filter this output as  `/32`

Comment: something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894329/finding-the-index-of-a-character-within-a-string

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63244804/how-to-find-ip-address-using-regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, I'd go with [Python's classes designed for dealing with IP addresses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html):

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Network

n = IPv4Network('172.4.5.3/32')
print(n.prefixlen)
```

Answer (score 0):

This splits the string into multiple strings (split where `/` occurs) and are put into an array. After this I select the last element of this array and prepend `/`.

```
input = "172.4.5.3/32"

output = '/' + input.split('/')[-1]

print(output)
```

output:

```
/32
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split it on '/', or use re.findall.

```
re.findall('/.*', '172.4.5.3/32')[0]
outputs '/32'
```

Comment: Isn't it better to always grab the last element since `/*` will always be at the end of the string

Comment: Oh yeah, fair point, could replace [0] with [-1] then, but seeing as there should only be 1, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I agree with you that it probably doesn't happen. But better safe than sorry ;)

Answer (score 0):

The python `.split()` method allows you to split a string into multiple items of a list, splitting on a separator of your choice.

```
ip_string = '172.4.5.3/32'
ip_subnet = ip_string.split('/')[1]
```

will fetch you your second value of that split string, i.e. the '32'

Comment: output = '/' + ip_subnet would then naturally give you your '/32'