# How do I find all indexes that have same string in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexing

In a game of Hangman, if the hidden word is `hello` and the player guesses `l` then I need to find the index of both locations.

Example:

```
word = "hello"
guess = "l"
position = word.index(guess)     #this helps me find the first one
```

I couldn't come up with any way to find the second. How am I able to do that?

Comment: also answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122291/python-find-char-in-string-can-i-get-all-indexes#11122355

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use `enumerate` and a list comprehension:

```
>>> s = "hello"
>>> indexes = [i for i, v in enumerate(s) if v == "l"]
>>> indexes
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for hangman:

```
>>> word = 'hello'
>>> guess = 'l'
>>> puzzle = ''.join(i if i == guess else '_' for i in word)
>>> print(puzzle)
__ll_
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do, is **preprocess** the word and have the list of indexes already available in a map so you do not have to iterate trough the string all the time, only once.

```
word = "hello"

map = {}

for i, c in enumerate(word):
    if (c in map):
        map[c].append(i)
    else:
        map[c] = [i]
```

Than, check that the letter guessed is in **map**. If it is, the letter exists otherwise it does not.