# python find the middle of “=” index in string

Tags: python, string, indexing, position

eg ‘“Hello Word” = "hello world";’, '"Hello=Word" = "Hello=Word"',find the middle of the "=" position by python.
I try this

```
>>>line = '"Hello=Word" = "Hello=Word"'
>>>index = line.index("=")
>>> index
6
```

I expect it return 13

Comment: The first `=` is at position 6...

Comment: What exactly is the logic here? Do you want the 2nd occurence of `'='`? The one in the middle? If so, what if there's an even number? Or maybe you want to find the first one that's not inclosed in quotes? There's a dozen ways to do this, but the question is which one is the most suitable.

Comment: Please, take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122291/python-find-char-in-string-can-i-get-all-indexes

Answer (score 1):

Probably a case for using regexes.

```
import re
re.search(r'^".*".*(=).*".*"$', line).start(1)
```

This assumes the string is of the form you specified, with double-quote `"` delimited strings on either side of an `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can also look on all occurrences of `=` in string via `enumerate(line)`. It returns you an `enumerate` object, which is iterable and contains tuples with format (index, item). So, that can be used like this:

```
>>> occurrences = [x[0] for x in enumerate(line) if x[1] == '=']
>>> occurrences
[6, 13, 21]
```

Now you should pick that index which you need.