# Find all occurrences of a character in a String

Tags: python, string, python-3.6

I'm really new to python and trying to build a Hangman Game for practice.
I'm using Python 3.6.1

The User can enter a letter and I want to tell him if there is any occurrence of that letter in the word and where it is.
I get the total number of occurrences by using `occurrences = currentWord.count(guess)`

I have `firstLetterIndex = (currentWord.find(guess))`, to get the index.
Now I have the index of the first Letter, but what if the word has this letter multiple times?
I tried `secondLetterIndex = (currentWord.find(guess[firstLetterIndex, currentWordlength]))`, but that doesn't work.
Is there a better way to do this? Maybe a build in function i can't find?

Comment: Hint: `find` has an optional argument `start`, which may be useful to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - find char in string - can I get all indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122291/python-find-char-in-string-can-i-get-all-indexes)

Comment: @Kevin I know that, I (tried) used it `secondLetterIndex`. I tried to start at the index of the first letter and end at the length of the word. Did not work.

Comment: If you're saying "I tried the two-argument form when I did `secondLetterIndex = (currentWord.find(guess[firstLetterIndex, currentWordlength]))`", you are not actually using the two argument form there. You are passing a single argument, `guess[firstLetterIndex, currentWordlength]`, to `find`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do this is to find the indices using list comprehension:

```
currentWord = "hello"

guess = "l"

occurrences = currentWord.count(guess)

indices = [i for i, a in enumerate(currentWord) if a == guess]

print indices
```

output:

```
[2, 3]
```

Comment: `enumerate()` might be a better option `[i for i, c in enumerate(currentWord) if c == guess]`

Comment: Can i call the 2 by itself? Like `indieces[0]` or something similar?

Comment: Yes, you could do that, if you want just the first element of the indices.

Answer (score 0):

I would maintain a second list of Booleans indicating which letters have been correctly matched.

```
>>> word_to_guess = "thicket"
>>> matched = [False for c in word_to_guess]
>>> for guess in "te":
...   matched = [m or (guess == c) for m, c in zip(matched, word_to_guess)]
...   print(list(zip(matched, word_to_guess)))
...
[(True, 't'), (False, 'h'), (False, 'i'), (False, 'c'), (False, 'k'), (False, 'e'), (True, 't')]
[(True, 't'), (False, 'h'), (False, 'i'), (False, 'c'), (False, 'k'), (True, 'e'), (True, 't')]
```

Comment: you can create matched as `matched = [False] * len(word_to_guess)` and avoid the loop

Comment: That's bad practice; it only works as intended for immutable values. It's what leads to countless questions like "What's wrong with my code that sets `x = [[]]*5`?".

Answer (score 0):

```
def findall(sub, s) :
    pos = -1
    hits=[]
    while (pos := s.find(sub,pos+1)) > -1 :
        hits.append(pos)
    return hits
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.