# Printing all string index locations of a specific character

Tags: python

If I have a `string` e.g. `s = '1084271054'`, and want to print all index locations of 0 e.g:

```
0 - 1, 7
```

What would be the most basic way to go about this?

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Show some of your work in regards to solving this problem and you might get some help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - find char in string - can I get all indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122291/python-find-char-in-string-can-i-get-all-indexes)

Comment: Sorry I'm a nub

Answer (score 2):

```
[i for i, c in enumerate(s) if c=='0']
Out: [1, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like

```
>>> idx=[i for i in range(len(s)) if s[i]=='0']
>>> idx
[1, 7]
```

**Edit:**

```
>>> print ', '.join(str(i) for i in idx)
1, 7
```

Comment: This seems good mate, is there any way to take out those pesky [ ] from the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the string into the enumerate function which returns an iterable of the indexes and characters. Then you can iterate over this and check if the character is `'0'` and if it is, print the index:

```
for i,c in enumerate(s):
    if c == '0':
        print(i)
```

which outputs:

```
1
7
```

---

If you want them on one line separated by commas, then you can use `str.join` with a generator:

```
print(', '.join(str(i) for i,c in enumerate(s) if c == '0'))
```

which gives:

```
1, 7
```