# Index of repeating character in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am checking for single quotation (') and printing its index, output is always  0

```
S="'abc','dsd''eeee'"
for i in S:
    if(i=="'"):
        print(S.index (i))
```

how to get 0,4....?

Comment: Related: [How to find char in string and get all the indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11122291/4518341)

Comment: you can try a simple list comprehension with if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) only finds the first occurrence. Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead.

```
for idx, i in enumerate(S):
    if i == "'":
        print(idx)
```

See [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/522563/4518341)

Comment: `str.index` does find later occurrences if you ask it nicely.

Comment: @superbrain yeah, but you'd need to know where to start from, which would require a state variable, which is annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `re` regular expression library for matching:

```
import re
pattern = r"'"
text = "'abc','dsd''eeee'"
indexes = [match.start() for match in re.finditer(pattern, text)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner using list comprehension -

```
S="'abc','dsd''eeee'"
[i[0] for i in enumerate(S) if i[1] == "'"]
```

```
[0, 4, 6, 10, 11, 16]
```